# optimize mysql query with cases and joins for speed performance increase

Tags: mysql

I have a slow sql query that I would like to optimize.

I have three different tables: subjects, cohorts, and schedules. Each course can have different subjects taught and each subject can have different schedules.

so a schedules table can have: computer science, physics, art.
The subjects in the subjects table for physics would be: electricity, magnetism, kinetics.
For art: modern, Michaelangelo, Abstract
For computer science: Networking, information security, compilers
and the cohorts table would have several courses from the schedules table.

We would like to perhaps use eloquent to do this as well.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT cohort_id, subject_id, skills_name,cohort_name,
    CASE
        WHEN end_date  < '2021-08-26' THEN 'ended'
        WHEN start_date  > '2021-08-26' THEN 'upcoming'
        ELSE 'running'
    END AS course_status
        FROM (
            SELECT schedules.cohort_id, schedules.date, schedules.subject_id, skills.name AS skills_name, cohorts.name AS cohort_name, MAX(schedules.date) as end_date, MIN(schedules.date) as start_date
            FROM schedules
            JOIN subjects ON schedules.subject_id = subjects.id
            JOIN skills ON subjects.skill_id = skills.id
            JOIN cohorts ON schedules.cohort_id = cohorts.id
            GROUP BY cohort_id
        ) a
    ) b
WHERE course_status IN ('running', 'upcoming')
ORDER BY `b`.`cohort_id`  DESC
LIMIT 4
```

This request takes 6 seconds locally and half a second on my dev server. I don't think 6 seconds locally is scalable (even though this is just on my local pc).

Other options I've considered but don't know if they make sense here are creating a stored procedure that inserts the computed columns into a new column that I will read from (I don't know if I like this option/if its the right thing to do here). Or, create a snapshot table where it will once a day create a table with all the data that I need that will be read by everyone that needs to do this function call.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: That is a very general list @Luuk, doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be written simpler.

- The outer `SELECT *` is not needed:
- The `WHERE course_status IN ('running', 'upcoming','ended')` is also not needed, because for `course_status` only the values `'running', 'upcoming','ended'` do exists.
- The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` can be moved to the inner sub-query.

This query should produce the same result:

```
SELECT cohort_id, subject_id, skills_name,cohort_name,
    CASE
        WHEN end_date  < '2021-08-26' THEN 'ended'
        WHEN start_date  > '2021-08-26' THEN 'upcoming'
        ELSE 'running'
    END AS course_status
        FROM (
            SELECT schedules.cohort_id, schedules.date, schedules.subject_id, skills.name AS skills_name, cohorts.name AS cohort_name, MAX(schedules.date) as end_date, MIN(schedules.date) as start_date
            FROM schedules
            JOIN subjects ON schedules.subject_id = subjects.id
            JOIN skills ON subjects.skill_id = skills.id
            JOIN cohorts ON schedules.cohort_id = cohorts.id
            GROUP BY cohort_id
            ORDER BY cohort_id
            LIMIT 4
        ) a
```

After this there are more improvements to be made.

For example:

- The sub-query is selecting some fields that are never used.
- Do the correct indexes exist?

Comment: Thanks, however the where you said was unnecessary is there for a basic check to see the worst case scenario.

Comment: perhaps a partition by can help here?

Comment: The 'worst case scenario` when using unneeded WHERE-clause will be that your query performance will not be optimal. This is because MySQL needs to check the WHERE-clause for every record.

Comment: I understand that, that bit of code will change depending on the specific case that I want to search by. So for that specifically I need it there.

Comment: @TalC - If you won't always be having a `WHERE` that  is always TRUE, then change your sample to exhibit that.